Flutter Dropdown button form field
In my DropdownButtonFormField2 I have a validator that cannot customize the padding of the error widget with the validator assigned. So is there any way by which I can customize the padding of the errorWidget by having the validator field included?

im not sure if there is more direct way to do it but one possible solution is to set a boolean variable make it true and wrap it in setstate in the validator where you indicate an error , make the padding value depend on it

Yes, it is currently managed with that solution but I don't think that is the standard way to implement it.

can you add a minimal reproducible code?

Okay will add the code

I think there is an issue in the text form field in the Flutter widget, and I guess these widgets follow the same pattern.
For your reference here is the link to the text form field issue I am attaching here.
PR
Flutter Issue

Thank you for sharing these details will have a look at the above links it is an open issue.
